# Can't find sound app after installation (20.04)

Tags: sound, launcher

I made a clean upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04, then installed sound app (sonido really, spanish version). Everything works fine except that the sound app is not in the available apps (launcher?) you get down right corner, with app icons. I took the app and installed from ubuntu software, that says it is installed....

Comment: More specific advice maybe able to provided if you provide clues as to how you installed it?  Was it a *deb*, *snap*, *flatpak*, compiled from source etc, where was it from etc.  I did a `apt-cache search sonido` and it returned no results (*for my release; and a query on all releases found no packages of that name for any release in Ubuntu repositories, nor results with `snap search sonido`*) .

Comment: I took it from ubuntu software, which is the only place where it appears as installed, though I cant launch it from there, and is not where it should, to be launched.

Answer (score 1):

Often times, you have to reboot or log out and log back in before the app will show amongst your list of installed apps. Also, if you are referring to the launcher bar on the left side of the screen, you must pin apps to the launcher.

If you're still having trouble, use the following instructions:

**First**, select the show applications icon on the lower left hand side of the screen (six dots in a square).

[image]

**Then**, search for the application by name.

**Once you start an app**, the icon will appear on the launcher. To pin the app to the launcher, right click on the icon and select to pin.

**Alternatively**, you can move your mouse into the upper left corner of your screen to trigger the "Activities" menu. Then, search for the app by name from your Activities screen. Again, once you open the app, the icon will show on your launcher. To pin the app to the launcher, right click on the icon and select to pin.

Comment: I answered though I do not know if maybe I should have commented here instead.

Comment: thanks for your detailed help. I did log off /on, reboot, and use the upper left activities option, and the lower right applications icon, did search by name on both, not there. The only place where I can see "sonido" as installed is Ubuntu Software app, that shows it but does not allow to launch it. I also searched sonido in the terminal with no resultas.